# How to design and validate access to a sub-resource in a jax-rs REST API avoiding code duplication?

Tags: java, rest, design-patterns, jax-rs

### Specifications

I'm currently developing a **JavaEE** app using **JAX-RS** and in the process of exposing various resources I'm faced with the following design dilemma that I haven't found a proper answer to.
Two entities, `Customer` and `Address`, are interconnected with the *One-To-One*, *Total
Participation* relationship, meaning one `Address` per `Customer`. Deriving from these I created a resource `CustomerResource` that exposes various endpoints relating to the `Customer` entity that lead to basic *CRUD* operations. Some of these endpoints are:

- POST   (/customers/create)
- GET    (/customers/get)
- GET    (/customers/get/{id})
- PUT    (/customers/update/{id})
- DELETE (/customers/delete/{id}

The problem arises when I create the second resource `AddressResource` which will handle endpoints relating to operations for the `Address` entity. This entity **cannot** exist without a `Customer` and as such I came to the decision to convey that using nested `URI` scheme, as opposed to using `QueryParams`. Now, as you can imagine, some of the endpoints that the `AddressResource` exposes are:

- POST   (/customers/{id}/address/create)
- GET    (/customers/{id}/address/get)
- PUT    (/customers/{id}/address/update)
- DELETE (/customers/{id}/address/delete)

I'm faced with validating **IF** the `Customer ID` exists and then continuing on to the actual operation that the endpoint entails. Looking the app design from a top down viewpoint, right after the `Resource` classes come the `Service` classes. For each `Resource` class there is a `Service` class which carry out any necessary business logic and call for the `DAO` classes to reflect all the necessary changes to the physical DB and the persistence context. So, any validation happens on the `Service` layer. The thing is that the `AddressService` class will have to make a call to check if the `Customer` exists using the `CustomerDao` class, which queries the database for the given `customerId` and returns its findings. If the customer exists then the `AddressDao` gets called to perform the corresponding query on the DB relating to the `Address` entities.

So, in a sense, **I want to avoid the coupling of the `Service` classes passing calls to multiple `Dao` classes, as well as, avoid any duplicate code that validation for multiple resources might lead to**.

This is due to the fact that I want to introduce a new *One-To-Many* resource that also requires validation on the `customerId` level and this would entail its `Service` class also calling the `CustomerDao`. I'm aware of the *N+1 query problem* and I'm keeping the nested resource depth at a maximum of 2. The validation would have to be performed regardless of the `URI` design as it derives from the `Total Participation` rule.

Sry for the long and maybe oversimplified explanation of the problem and thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First, "One-To-One, Total Participation relationship, meaning one Address per Customer" also means "just one Customer at one Address". In this case you don't need separate Entity for Address, it might be the part of Customer.

So, let me suppose, you meant One-To-Many relation: "many Customers at one Address". Didn't you? In this case you can create Addresses as a dictionary with separate resource then bind that to some Customers with web-method of Customer resource.

Finally, to avoid code duplication you can encapsulate business logic within appropriate facades then inject those anywhere you need like:

```
@Inject
CustomerFacade customerFacade;

...

customerFacade.bindAddress(customerId, addressId);
```

Comment: While I do agree that I could just place the `Address` within the `Customer` entity, the project specifications, for various reasons, are not allowing me to do so. The relationship of Customer-To-Address is a One-To-One and the physical DB contains two different tables for each entity. What do you mean by creating a dictionary? A root resource (e.g. /addresses/{id}/users) ?

Comment: "Dictionary" is meaning "the list of addresses available", each of those can be bound then to a number of Customers in case, for example, when some Customers are resided  the same building.